# Why can't the return value of a transaction be included in the transaction receipt?

Tags: transactions, evm, receipts

Shouldn't this be possible as the return value will be known when the receipt is created?

Comment: I can think of two possible reasons: 1) a contract can return an arbitrary amount of data, 2) The result is redundant (for example tx receipts are also not stored in the blockchain). Since you can always create a log entry with the result, perhaps creating a special log with the return value is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function which does not need the blockchain (or EVM) to get the return value, then you can get it directly. Such functions are `view` and `pure` functions. Those functions get the value from your own node and there's no need to go through the EVM.

If the function is not `pure` or `view`, then it will go through EVM execution - it has to be mined in a block. Therefore the execution is not instant and you can only get the return value after the transaction is mined in a block.

Comment: It would still be nice if the interface would allow for return values of transactions to be passed to javascript.  If I invoke a contract in Solidity I can get the return value.  Is that because even the invocation of the contract is considered part of the same transaction so it's all internal?  I assume so.  But the library could still be done in a way that would allow access to return values.  For instance, by automatically turning return values into events and automatically parsing the events after mining.

Comment: "and you can only get the return value after the transaction is mined in a block." That's what OP is asking for: a return value in the transaction receipt (once the block is mined). But no, a return value is not available for transactions.

Comment: Is there a good reason for this beyond "the value included in the transaction needs to resolve on the blockchain"? What if you (hypothetically) want to return a value that isn't involved in the transaction? That seems like a relatively reasonable feature to be included?